# PHP regex split by first two spaces

Tags: php, regex

Heres my code right now:

```
preg_split( '/ {2}/', $searchString );
```

How should i set the {} that it is splitting the first two spaces and ignores the rest so:

```
foo foo foo foo
```

get:

```
foo|foo|foo foo
```

EDIT: Because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39270293/2593099) answer i recognized regex isn't even necessary. I didn't know that it is possible to limit explode.

Comment: I don't quite get what the pipes should mean? Do you want to replace the first two spaces by pipes? Or should that indicate, that you want to end up with a total of 3 elements?

Comment: Maybe [`preg_split( '/\s+/', $searchString, 3)`](https://ideone.com/OYYlFG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply limits to the number of replacements done with **PREG** functions.

To get what you need you could do the following:

```
$newString = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '|', 'foo foo foo foo', 2);
```

This will replace first 2 sets of white characters with a pipe.

Comment: Shame on me ._. it is possible to set limits to explode too. So i can just use explode( ' ', 'foo foo foo foo', 3 )

Comment: It will just explode the string, it won't add the pipes as the OP wanted

Comment: Yeah i just used that to show how the string should be separated into array elements. I marked your question as accepted because its the most accurate for my (inaccurate and bad question) ;)

Comment: ah, ok :) I didn't realise you were the OP

Answer (score 0):

Use [third argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php#refsect1-function.preg-split-parameters) for `preg_split`:

```
print_r(preg_split( '/ /', 'foo foo foo foo', 3));
// Outputs: Array ( [0] => foo [1] => foo [2] => foo foo )
```

After that you can `implode` result array with `|`.

But it's better to use `preg_replace` with `limit` as in @jerdzej answer.